# Confusing error: "wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am calling a method from app/views/posts/_post.html.erb using this code segment:

```
<% if post.user_id != current_user.id %>
   | <%= vote(post, "up") %>
     <%= vote(post, "down") %>
<% end %>
```

which calls this method in app/helpers/posts_helper.rb:

```
 def vote(post, direction)
    link_to icon("thumbs-#{direction}"), vote_post_path(post, type: "#{direction}"), :remote => true, style: "color: #{class_for_voted(direction)}"
 end
```

and I am getting a "**wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)**" error. I don't understand why the error comes up as I am sending two parameters and getting two parameters in the method.

Any idea what might be wrong? If you need any other info please let me know.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you give the full error trace?

Comment: @anime, sorry about that. i thought it was really weird but it was my stupid mistake instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown your stacktrace (yet?), but I wonder if the error is not actually about `vote()`, but about a line inside it.

How many args is `icon()` supposed to take?  `class_for_voted()`?